# List/Set of objects in sub-query HQL

Tags: hibernate, set, subquery, hql

I am trying to query using HQL. Is it possible to return a set/list of objects in a sub-query in hql? If so, how to do it.

Eg:

```
SELECT ta1.id, ta1.name, obj FROM table1 AS ta1, table2 AS obj WHERE obj.id = ta1.id;
```

table2 will return a list of objects, and I would like to retrieve them as a `list` or `set`. So, the response will contain id, name, set of obj. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

implement resulttransformer. The code is here to illustrate, i havent got a IDE/compiler here

```
class ResultTransformer : Resulttransformer
{
    public List transformList(List collection)
    {
        ArrayList<T1> result = new ArrayList<T1>();
        for (int tuple : collection)
        {
            T1 t1 = GetT1ById(result, tuple[0]);
            if (T1 == null)
            {
                result.add(t1)
            }
            t1.T2s.add(new T2(tuple[3], ...));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases)
    {
        return tuple;
    }
}
```